# Ruby on Rails 3 and how to make web service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services

I tried to make this to work, but I got "uninitialized constant ActionWebService" error when I use standard (old) actionwebservice, but if I install datanoise's actionwebservice gem I can't settup project properly to use them (in Gemfile with gem Bundler).

There is a alternative? Someone make this think to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand datanoise's gem is not rails 3 compatible. On the github Page it says that it's version 2.3.2. However here is a [rails 3 fork](https://github.com/ywen/actionwebservice)

Why can't you use [ActiveResource](http://rails-nutshell.labs.oreilly.com/ch08.html)? Do you have some sort of specific requirement not to use REST?

Answer (score 2):

Quite a few people on github have forked the datanoise 2.3.2 actionwebservice, and have Rails3-compatible versions. Not sure which one works best, but I know this one does:

gem 'actionwebservice', :git => "git://github.com/dnordberg/actionwebservice.git"

Comment: I tried with dnordberg's gem since i am a relative newby to RoR (not to programming though), I am not very sure what other missing steps are. I added AWS gem, SOAP4R (github.com/felipec/soap4r.git) and followed the instruction here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ws-rubyrails/index.html. But I just cant get the WS to work. I keep getting route error. (apparently rails hasn't recognised it as a WS yet, and hence looking for appropriate routes?). Will you able to provide a quick run down on the steps needed on rails 3.x ? Thanks!