# actionwebservice and rails 3 /

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rubygems, actionwebservice

I'm on a rails 3 project trying to install actionwebservice using:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'actionwebservice', :git => 'https://github.com/ywen/actionwebservice.git'
```

And I get the error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    actionwebservice depends on
      activerecord (= 2.3.5)

    rails (= 3.0.4) depends on
      activerecord (3.0.4)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993500/ruby-on-rails-3-and-how-to-make-web-service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.
Try this gem: https://github.com/dnordberg/actionwebservice

```
gem 'actionwebservice', :git => "git://github.com/dnordberg/actionwebservice.git"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
gem install actionwebservice --include-dependencies
```