# Using actionwebservice and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

We want to use actionwebservice for some SOAP integration. We were able to install it however using it causes an error. Here's my code:

```
class HelloMessageApi < ActionWebService::Base
    api_method :hello_message,
               :expects => [{:firstname=>:string},
                            {:lastname=>:string}],
               :returns => [:string]
end
```

The error returned is

> uninitialized constant
>   ActionWebService

When I do a `gem list` I can see the gem installed, what am I missing? Please help.

Comment: Yes it is: `gem 'actionwebservice'`. Somehow I am thinking that this could be a version problem? Ack.

Comment: btw, possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993500/ruby-on-rails-3-and-how-to-make-web-service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993500/ruby-on-rails-3-and-how-to-make-web-service). and yes, why can't use ActiveResource like @Nick Gorbikoff offers?

Comment: No. I cannot use `ActiveResource`, we need to integrate an existing SOAP service to our ruby app. But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Looking around I think I might have the same problem with this one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156018/actionwebservice-and-rails-3) - which was not solved. Losing hope, thinking of other options.

Comment: The link below walks through the process in a little more detail and discusses the error you are getting:
http://enterpriserails.chak.org/full-text/chapter-16-an-xml-rpc-service