# Ruby on Rails 3: SOAP-based Web Service (server-side) - which (actionwebservice) Gem should I take?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, soap, rubygems

I have the requirement to offer a SOAP-based web service in my Rails 3 application (yes, I would prefer REST-based web service but that's not my decision unfortunately) - Rails 3.1.1. if that matters.

I have looked up several threads at stackoverflow that deal with the topic "Rails 3 + SOAP Web Services", I also browsed rubygems.org and github in search of a clear solution. My researches however seem to give me the conclusion that a) REST-ful web services is the Rails-way to go (ok, nothing new) and b) there is not **the** preferred SOAP gem/github project for Rails 3.

For example if I search for "actionwebservice" on github, I found that there are 109 forks - *yikes* - of what seems to be the "original" (Rails 2.*) actionwebservice gem: https://github.com/datanoise/actionwebservice/network. At rubygems.org the "actionwebservice" query also presents more than a dozen results.

Any hints, what would be the way to go? To clarify: I do not want to **consume** a Web Service in my Rails 3 application, I want to offer one (i.e. server side, not client side)

Thanks in advance.
Klaus

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993500/ruby-on-rails-3-and-how-to-make-web-service) it looks like you might try forking the Action Web Service code on Github, updating it to work with the latest Rails and then using the new gem... might even get some cred for updating it.

Although that would be a bit of work...

[Soap4R](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_web_services.htm) also may provide a solution (and a more recent one) but it too has been ageing.

Comment: I have tried [wash_out](https://github.com/roundlake/wash_out) which seems to be quite straight forward to use.